# PHP Multidimensional array searching for combinations of values in array

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, key

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$array =
  Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [zoneId] => 2 [buildingId] => 2 [typeId] => 2 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [zoneId] => 2 [buildingId] => 2 [typeId] => 1 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [id] => 6 [zoneId] => 6 [buildingId] => 17 [typeId] => 2 ) )
```

And I would like to search if the combination of, for example, [buildingId] => 2, [typeId] => 2 exists is array 0, 1 or 2.

I tried the following:

```
$keyType = array_search(2, array_column($array, 'typeId'));
$keyBuilding = array_search(2, array_column($array, 'buildingId'));

if(is_numeric($keyType)&&is_numeric($keyBuilding)){
     echo 'Combination does exists'
}
```

This works, but gives also a false positive if I would search for [buildingId] => 17, [typeId] => 1. How can I solve this?

*edit*

**I would also like to know if a combination is not in the array, how can I arrange that?**

```
if($result == false){
echo 'does not exists';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$buildingId = 2;
$typeId = 2;
$result = false;
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if ($val['buildingId'] == $buildingId && $val['typeId'] == $typeId) {
        $result = $key; // If you want the key in the array
        $result = $val; // If you want directly the entry you're looking for
        break; // So that you don't iterate through the whole array while you already have your reuslt
    }
}
```

Comment: if I would like to know that combination typeId = 17 and buildingId = 1 does not exists, how would I do that?

Comment: @LoesVisser If no rsult is found, `$result` evaluates to `false` after the `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$keyTypeExistsAndHaveSameValue = isset($array['typeId']) && $array['typeId'] === 2;
$keyBuildingExistsAndHaveSameValue = isset($array['buildingId']) && $array['buildingId'] === 2;

if($keyTypeExistsAndHaveSameValue && $keyBuildingExistsAndHaveSameValue){
     echo 'Combination does exists'
}
```

This code check if typeId & buildingId keys exist but it also check if its values are 2 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this

```
$keyType = array_search(1, array_column($array, 'typeId'));
$keyBuilding = array_search(17, array_column($array, 'buildingId'));

if(is_numeric($keyType)||is_numeric($keyBuilding)){
  echo 'Combination does exists';
}
```

Now here you need or operator instead of and operator because you want either typeid = 1 exists or building id = 17 exists.

If I have understand your question correctly then you are trying to do something like this, right ?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a foreach loop to get the actual array number, the other solution don't seems to answer what you're looking for, which is to get the index number.

> I would like to search if the combination of, for example, [buildingId] => 2, [typeId] => 2 exists is array 0, 1 or 2.

EDIT: This code is just sample code to show how you would get the array index number, in a production environment you would save the matching arrays, comparison figures are not hard coded, etc...

```
$array = array(array('id' => 2, 'zoneId' => 2, 'buildingId' => 2, 'typeId' => 2),
            array('id' => 4, 'zoneId' => 2, 'buildingId' => 2, 'typeId' => 2),
            array('id' => 6, 'zoneId' => 6, 'buildingId' => 17, 'typeId' => 2));


foreach ($array as $building => $building_details)
{
    if ($building_details['buildingId'] === 2 && $building_details['typeId'] === 2)
    {
        echo 'Array number ' . $building . ' matches criteria<br>';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array number 0 matches criteria
Array number 1 matches criteria
```

You can view this snippet online [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ce3472d663327b340e758c2bfcc10b1258f0126).